# Ringbuffer over a const generic Array in Rust

Tags: rust, generics, circular-list

I implemented this generic ringbuffer over a const generic array with the usage of the `MaybeUninit` type.
Is there something which is maybe unsound (having the lines with drop_in_place in mind) or which could be optimized?
Thanks in advance

```
#![feature(inline_const)]

use core::mem::MaybeUninit;
use core::ptr;

struct Ringbuffer<T, const N: usize> { 
    buffer: [MaybeUninit<T>; N],
    read: usize,
    write: usize,
    size: usize
}

impl <T, const N: usize> Ringbuffer<T, N> {
    pub const fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            buffer: [const { MaybeUninit::<T>::zeroed() }; N],
            read: 0,
            write: 0,
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
        if N == 0 {
            return;
        }
    
        if self.size >= N {
            unsafe {
               ptr::drop_in_place(self.buffer[self.write].as_mut_ptr()); 
            }
        
            self.buffer[self.write].write(value);
            self.wrap_inc_write();
        
        } else {
            self.buffer[self.write].write(value);
            self.wrap_inc_write();
            self.inc_size();
        }
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self)  -> Option<T> {
        if N == 0 {
            return None;
        }
    
        if self.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }
    
        let ret = unsafe {
            self.buffer[self.read].assume_init_read()
        };
    
        self.wrap_inc_read();
        self.dec_size();
    
        Some(ret)
    }

    pub fn skip(&mut self) {
    
        if N == 0 {
            return;
        }
    
        if self.is_empty() {
            return;
        }
    
        unsafe {
            ptr::drop_in_place(self.buffer[self.read].as_mut_ptr());
        }
    
        self.wrap_inc_read();
        self.dec_size();
    }

    pub fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&T> {
        if N == 0 {
            return None;
        }
    
        if self.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }
    
        let ret = unsafe {
            self.buffer[self.read].assume_init_ref()  
        };
    
        Some(ret)
    }

    pub fn size(&self) -> usize {
        self.size
    }

    pub fn capacity(&self) -> usize {
        N
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.size == 0
    }

    pub fn is_full(&self) -> bool {
        self.size == N
    }

    fn wrap_inc_read(&mut self) {
        self.read = (self.read + 1) % N;
    }

    fn wrap_inc_write(&mut self) {
        self.write = (self.write + 1) % N;
    }

    fn inc_size(&mut self) {
        self.size += 1;
    }

    fn dec_size(&mut self) {
        self.size -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know [`heapless::HistoryBuffer`](https://docs.rs/heapless/latest/heapless/struct.HistoryBuffer.html)?

Comment: No, I didn't know that one. Thanks, but I was mostly implementing this because I want to keep dependencies low and for practice. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly sound to me after looking through docs and the code. Nothing to add, but there is one more way for implementing your `push`, one that may be effectively the same or slower, though still using some unsafe:

```rust
        if self.size >= N {
            unsafe {
                mem::replace(&mut self.buffer[self.write], MaybeUninit::new(value)).assume_init();
            }
            self.wrap_inc_write();
        }
```

All you need to know is how MaybeUninit works, and this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.drop_in_place.html#safety

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

On thing I forgot is to drop the elements when the Ringbuffer gets dropped, else their destructor never gets run.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=225213ad5b7ff4ac185fff2798fd9837
I verified it with this little example, when I do not implement Drop for Ringbuffer like this, only the value 1 is dropped.